# How to connect a Rails App on one server (DigitalOcean droplet) to a MongoDB server on another server via private connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ssh

I'm trying to setup two servers: one for my App and another for my DB (MongoDB).

Each server sits on its own droplet (VPS) and both servers can talk to each other via private network.

I want to completely close my db server off the internet and only allow connections from the private network.

I can connect to the server via `ssh` tunnel like so: `ssh -L 4321:localhost:27017 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub myuser@myserver_ip` but how can I configure Rails/Mongoid to connect to the server the same way (using the private network rather than connect via internet)?

Is it at all possible?